# Massive list in c# & wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, list, optimization

I have a list consisting of all the US Zip codes, each with 3 elements.  Thus the list is ~45,000 x 3 strings.  What is the best way to load this, essentially the most efficient/optimized?  Right now I have a foreach loop running it, and every time it gets to the loading point it hangs.  Is there a better approach?

**Edit**

The usage of this is for the user to be able to type in a zip code and have the city and state displayed in two other text boxes.  Right now I have it set to check as the user types, an after the dirt number is entered it freezes up, I believe at the ZipCodes codes = new ZipCodes()

This is the code I'm currently using.  I left one of the `zipCode.Add` statements in, but deleted the other 44,999.

```
struct ZipCode
{
    private String cvZipCode;
    private String cvCity;
    private String cvState;

    public string ZipCodeID { get { return cvZipCode; } }
    public string City { get { return cvCity; } }
    public string State { get { return cvState; } }

    public ZipCode(string zipCode, string city, string state)
    {
        cvZipCode = zipCode;
        cvCity = city;
        cvState = state;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return City.ToString() + ", " + State.ToString();
    }
}

class ZipCodes
{
    private List<ZipCode> zipCodes = new List<ZipCode>();
    public ZipCodes()
    {            
        zipCodes.Add(new ZipCode("97475","SPRINGFIELD","OR"));            
    }

    public IEnumerable<ZipCode> GetLocation()
    {
        return zipCodes;
    }
    public IEnumerable<ZipCode> GetLocationZipCode(string zipCode)
    {
        return zipCodes;
    }
    public IEnumerable<ZipCode> GetLocationCities(string city)
    {
        return zipCodes;
    }
    public IEnumerable<ZipCode> GetLocationStates(string state)
    {
        return zipCodes;
    }
}

private void LocateZipCode(TextBox source, TextBox destination, TextBox destination2 = null)
    {
        ZipCodes zips = new ZipCodes();
        string tempZipCode;
        List<ZipCode> zipCodes = new List<ZipCode>();

        try
        {
            if (source.Text.Length == 5)
            {
                tempZipCode = source.Text.Substring(0, 5);

                dataWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

                destination.Text = zipCodes.Find(searchZipCode => searchZipCode.ZipCodeID == tempZipCode).City.ToString();
                if (destination2.Text != null)
                {
                    destination2.Text = zipCodes.Find(searchZipCode => searchZipCode.ZipCodeID == tempZipCode).State.ToString();
                }
            }
            else destination2.Text = "";
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            destination.Text = "Invalid Zip Code";
            if (destination2 != null)
            {
                destination2.Text = "";
            }            
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you should provide more details. How, when, where is this data used, where does it come from, web or client app,...

Comment: Also consider threading and use StringBuilder if you concatenate a large amount of strings.

Comment: If you load it all than there would be a portion that (might) get fragmented in memory.

Comment: You say "loading" it. I'm not sure whether that means populating of the List<ZipCode> or the rendering of it.

Comment: Running the above code, the freezing occurs in the `LocateZipCode` method on the line `ZipCodes zips = new ZipCodes();'  I set a breakpoint there, and when hitting F11 to StepInto, it freezes.  VS, is still responsive, but the project doesn't respond at all.
'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the responses, I really do appreciate them.  A couple I didn't really understand, but I know that's my own lack of knowledge in certain areas of c#.  In researching them though, I did stumble across a different solution that had worked beautifully, using a `Dictionary<T>` instead of a List.  Even without using a `BackgroundWorker`, it loads on app start-up in about 5 seconds.  I had heard of `Dictionary<T>` before, but until now had never had a cause to use/research it, so this was doubly beneficial to me.  Thanks again for all the assistance!

Answer (score 3):

There are several options that depend on your use case and target client machines.

1. Use paged controls. Use existing paged control variants (eg. telerik) which support paging. This way you will deal with smaller subset of the data available.
2. Use search/filter controls. Force users to enter partial data to reduce the size of the data you need to show.
3. Using observable collection will cause performance problems as framework provided class does not support bulk load. Make your own observable collection which supports bulk loading (which does not raise collection changed event on every element you add). On a list of 5-10.000 members I've seen loading times reduced from 3s to 0.03s.
4. Use async operations when loading data from db. This way UI stays responsive and you have a chance to inform users about the current operation. This improves the perceived performance immensely.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading all of the items, try loading on demand. For instance, when user enters the first three letters then query the list and return only matching items. Many controls exists for this purpose both in silverlight and ajax.